# Modify file permissions in Android from code not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, chmod

Some time ago I created an application with private Shared Preferences. Now I'm creating a related application that needs to check some of the previous application preferences. The problem I'm facing is that the previous application source code is in a computer I can't access until  next month. Since I don't want to wait that long I thought that, since my device is rooted, I might be able to modify the preferences file permissions to be able to access it so I can publish both applications as soon as I get the previous application code back.

The preferences file is located in /data/data/my.package/shared_prefs. If I access it with adb shell and use **chmod 777** the file permissions are modified and I can access the preferences, but eventually the permissions will go back to 660. I tried to change them from code using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /data/data/my.package/shared_prefs/my_preferences.xml");
```

The permissions aren't modified. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is each command run from `exec()` is [executed in a separate native process](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29). Therefore your `su` command doesn't affect the second call to `exec()`.

Try this instead:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su; chmod 777 /data/data/my.package/shared_prefs/my_preferences.xml");
```

Comment: I tried it and it's still not working. If I use it with two diferent execs I see a Toast saying I got root permissions. If I use it in a single exec like you you did there's no Toast and the file permissions aren't modified :(

Comment: errors: `java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su;Working Directory: null Environment: null`

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream suOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
    suOutputStream
            .writeBytes("chmod 777 /data/data/my.package/shared_prefs/my_preferences.xml\n");
    suOutputStream.flush();
    suOutputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    suOutputStream.flush();
    suProcess.waitFor();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: I just tried it. The file permissions aren't modified and the process never ends. If I place a Log.d after suProcess.waitFor() should it be executed? Cause I did it and it's never executed.

Comment: I don't actually have a rooted phone, so can't test. Answer was inspired from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9884310/1440076). Good luck John ;)

Comment: very slow, and how are you supposed to use it for FOLDER?

Comment: chmod works on folders. Search for "chmod recursive".